# Five numbers in kernel version?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, 21.10, versions

AFAIK linux kernels versions consist of four numbers, each with a distinct meaning.

However when looking into the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer tool, it shows me kernel versions with five numbers:

[image]

What is the meaning of the fifth number?

Are there actually two kernels installed on my Kubuntu 21.10 system? When looking into boot partition I can see only a single set of files with *5.13.0-28* numbering with four places.

Comment: Did you look at the various wiki pages?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ etc

Comment: I didn't understand that the answer is there due to the inconsistent use of '.' and '-'. So the two trailing numbers are ABI Number and Upload Number?